Excel STOCKHISTORY for AMD
I have two problems with tracking the AMD stock using Excel STOCKHISTORY using this formula:
=STOCKHISTORY("AMD","10/14/2024","10/23/2024")


The values for the stock at closing are not right. In reality, the stock has values of around $150



For 10/18/2024 there are no values, as if there weren't any transactions. But the stock had transactions at that date.

I get the same erroneous results if I use Excel Online.
The equivalent Google Sheets function:
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMD","close","10/14/2024","10/24/2024")

works fine
Any ideas why it is wrong?
I am using Excel 365, Version 2409, Built 18025.20160

You need to specify the exchange for this instrument:
=STOCKHISTORY("XNAS:AMD","10/14/2024","10/23/2024")


The documentation now indicates that the data will be pulled from "from the default exchange for the instrument", but it does not indicate how that default exchange is determined.

Thanks for the reply!
Turns out they were showing me Arrow Minerals Ltd (XASX: AMD).
That’s pretty wild. Who would expect AMD from the Australian Securities Exchange instead of NASDAQ?
